# array statement in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a  matrix

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

I want to combine the first element with the other element of the same matrix and create new matrix.

x and y  is ndarray
I want to do this code in python

```
for i=0 to 3 do
    for j=0 to 3 do
      if  x[0][0]<x[i][j] then 
            t[i][j]=1
      else
           t[i][j]=0
```

In python:

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
y=[]
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        if x[0][0]< x[i][j]:
            y.append(1)
        else:
            y.append(0)
```

out put:

```
>>> t
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Is this statement correct ?

Comment: this is a very confusing question ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when I run your code exactly as stated, I get this value for y, not the value you pasted:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I suspect what you're trying to do is not actually what you have written here, but assuming it is, here's a much easier way to achieve the same result:

```
>>> np.where(x > x[0,0], 1, 0).flatten()
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: what? didn't you just provide your own answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
output = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    y=[]
    for j in range(0, 3):
        if x[0][0]< x[i][j]:
            y.append(1)
        else:
            y.append(0)
     output.append(y)
print output
```

but its kind of hard to tell from your question

but a better solution would be

```
map(lambda tmp:map(int,tmp),(x+x[0,0])[0,0] < x)
```

or even better use jterraces solution with numpy

Comment: but if I want to combine the element `x[1][1]` this gives `>>> output
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`,  normally it gives me a matrix of 3 lines and 3 columns.`>>> output
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`,

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "combine the element x[1][1]"

Comment: it means:x[1][1]=5 combine with all   x[i][j] (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), if 5<2 then  y[0][1]=1